# why sometimes browser can not display a checkbox correctly

Tags: html, jsf-2, browser, checkbox, jsf-2.2

I'm using JSF 2.2.6 with Glassfish 4 server and https. I found uncertainly displaying a checkbox type in web browser either Chrome or Firefox. Sometimes it shows, some not. I often found that it occurs on the 1st checkbox.

At the generated html page, I observed it showed "checked"="checked" correctly, but at browser it showed unchecked.

I don't know how to solve this. Thanks.

.xhtml codes:

```
<h:form id="usersF">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr class="success" >
            <th class="text-center">#{msgs.Index}</th>
            <th class="text-center">#{adminMsgs.Username}</th>
            <th class="text-center">#{msgs.Email}</th>
            <th class="text-center">#{adminMsgs.Validity}</th>
            <th class="text-center">#{adminMsgs.LastLogin}</th>
            </tr>
           <tbody>
            <ui:repeat id="usersTable" value="#{usersManagedBean.dtmdl}" var="users"   
                                                                   varStatus="status">
              <tr>
              <td class="text-center">#{status.index+usersManagedBean.pagination.currentPage*usersManagedBean.pageSize+1}</td>   
             <td >
            <h:link id="cedit1" value="#{users.username}" outcome="adminUserDetails">
             <f:param  name="userName" value="#{users.username}"/> 
            </h:link>
            <h:outputText value="  "/>
            </td>  
            <td>#{users.email}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" jsf:id="user#{status.index}" jsf:value="#{users.validity}" />
             </td>
             <td> #{users.lastLoginDate} </td>
            </tr>
          </ui:repeat>
          </tbody>
         </table>
    ...
    <h:selectOneMenu id="pageSize"  class=" btn"   value="#{usersManagedBean.pageSize}">
        <f:selectItems  id="pageSizeValue" value="#{usersManagedBean.page}" var="pg"
                                                                    itemLabel="#{pg}" 
                                                                    itemValue="#{pg}"/>
        <f:ajax  execute="pageSize pageSizeValue" listener="#{usersManagedBean.recreatePageSize}" render="usersF"/>
     </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>


Generated html code (shown at browser):

      <tbody>
       <tr>
       <td class="text-center">1</td>   
      <td><a id="usersF:usersTable:0:cedit1" name="usersF:usersTable:0:cedit1" href="/jsfBootstrapMV/admin/adminUserDetails.xhtml?userName=admin">admin</a>  
        </td>  
      <td>
     </td>
     <td class="text-center"><input id="usersF:usersTable:0:user" name="usersF:usersTable:0:user" checked="checked" type="checkbox" />
     </td>
      <td> Mon May 05 22:12:08 ICT 2014</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="text-center">2</td>   
     <td><a id="usersF:usersTable:1:cedit1" name="usersF:usersTable:1:cedit1" href="/jsfBootstrapMV/admin/adminUserDetails.xhtml?userName=sarawut">sarawut</a>  
         </td>  
         <td>
      </td>
     <td class="text-center"><input id="usersF:usersTable:1:user" name="usersF:usersTable:1:user" checked="checked" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
     <td> Tue May 06 19:34:38 ICT 2014
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What about the css that is being applied to the checkbox..? can you replicate this issue somehow..?

Comment: I used Bootstrap 3 to apply for this iterative checkbox. When I click reload button (to change a number of rows, pagination), at the 1st time it shows correctly. Later and trying several times, sometimes it does not show. And I try to print(console) at JSF managedbean; it prints correctly.

Comment: Noted: it will occur one of 10-20 times.

Comment: Now I known the issue; it came from my application invoking a business method during the 2nd phase(Apply Request Value) of JSF cycle. Thus I change my app to reload data from back-end during rendering phase(the 6th phase) instead. The issue now disappears.